An easy way to INCLUDE folders in VS 2022 Find and Replace?
I'm dealing with a pretty niche problem. I'm trying to search my codebases' entire solution (namely web apps) for a given string (so that I can find references to a route, for instance), but I want to exclude certain files or folders- I will elaborate on the 'include' portion later on. The reason I want to do this is that there are a few files that you would probably never want to search- bootstrap files, Migration metadata, so on. I used to use the standard Ctrl+F "Quick Search" window, which was tedious to say the least. Thankfully, I recently found out that if you do Ctrl+Shift+F, you can find a much more elaborate "Find and Replace" menu. From this menu, there are a couple ways to exclude files or folders.
Approach 1: You can either search the current file, a folder, a specific set of folders, etc. In other words, this will limit what you're searching in. While this does allow me to exclude folders, it's sort of the nuclear option. Instead of searching the entire solution, I now have to manually go through and search every folder, which probably wouldn't save me much time at all. You can also click the "Choose Search Folders" ("...") button next to the "Look in" drop down, which lets you select multiple search folders. However, I am faced with a similar problem here. I now have to add several folders to search in. This isn't a very large project, but I'm sure you can see how this approach wouldn't scale well if I'm trying to search an entire solution. You can save the folders to search, but you will still have to add any new ones to the list.
Approach 2: This is the approach that saved me a lot of time. Rather than including specific folders, you can rather exclude certain folders using the !**; syntax in the "File types" dropdown (as is Microsoft tradition, it's not documented very well, but you can find it here. I found this solution from this stackoverflow post). Now these folders will be excluded from your "Look in" criteria. This approach is much easier for searching a solution, now you can just exclude the Migrations folder, for instance.
However, the challenge I'm facing is, I am trying to go with Approach 2, but now I need a way to include folders. The reason for this is that I have a couple of folders in an ASP.NET MVC web app, Content and Scripts that contain bootstrap and jQuery dependencies that I don't want to search, but I also have custom CSS and JS, respectively, that I do want to search nested in subfolders under those same directories. The dependency files are located right in the root folder. So my question is as follows: Is there an easy way to include these subfolders, but not include the parent folder (an "include" to contrast the "exclude" feature)? Or rather, since I don't think this feature is available in the "Find and Replace" menu, is there a better approach to gain something similar to this? Here's a photo example:


There are a few approaches I can think of to this, but none are ideal.
I could move them to a separate folder, but then I would have to update all the references (I also think nuget puts them in these folders by default for older apps... there's no libman.json). Not a big deal, but I would prefer to keep the structure the same to keep our legacy codebases consistent.
I could go and add every folder in the solution except for the parent folders in the "Look in" box, and I would also have to manually add any new folders, leading to uncertainty over all the folders were searched or not. Likewise, I could manually search every folder, but then there more potential for things being overlooked.
I think the best approach that I can think of is I might be able to exclude every library .js and .css file manually (I haven't tested it yet). If this approach works, it would allow me to search properly. In this case, there aren't many files to exclude, but as like before, this would get pretty tedious if there were a lot of files to exclude... I would also have to add any new files yet again.
Finally, I could just manually do a secondary search within my custom CSS and JS file folders, which is probably the easiest, but I suppose that I want to find a good approach to do something like this in the future.
Is there any straightforward approach to include folders in Find and Replace that were previously excluded?
